# Delphi extract records where a field has a specific value

Tags: database, delphi

I am trying to get records from a database where a field has a specific value.

Here is what I have written so far.

With AddressListTable do
while AddressListTable.FieldByName('ContactID').AsInteger = I do
while not Eof do

So I would like to display all records that have a ContactID value of I in a MCListBox.
Currently what happens is it shows all the record unfiltered.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you work with database like with simple record set file?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question?

Comment: I mean: something like `SELECT * from AddressListTable WHERE ContactID = I` should perform all the work

Comment: See DataSet.Filter property https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter or use parametrized where SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MBo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844416/mbo) told it's better to use a QueryDataset and do it in your query sql code. If you insist on doing this with a Table dataset, you can do it on AfterOpen property. Something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ADOTable1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
bm: TBookmark;
MyIntValue: Integer;
begin
bm := DataSet.GetBookmark;
DataSet.DisableControls;
try

DataSet.First;
while not DataSet.Eof do
begin
  if DataSet.FieldByName('MyFieldName').AsInteger = MyIntValue then
    //do something like add to your Listbox
  else
    //do something else

  DataSet.Next;
end;
finally
DataSet.GotoBookmark(bm);
DataSet.EnableControls;
end;
end;
```

Comment: I think you and MBo are right, I need to learn how to use SQl statements. I have a book on firedac,  I am hoping that will get me started in the right direction.